# How can I build a Custom Link Button that navigates to a URL specified in a Custom URL Field?

Tags: url, custom-link

We currently use a couple of URL fields to deep link to external systems.  I'd like to create buttons that can navigate to those URLs.

Creating a **Custom Link** & populating it with a URL Field didn't work because Salesforce automatically URL Encodes all fields that are added to **Custom Links**.

So even though my URL Field may have a legitimate URL (like say: http://www.salesforce.com), when I put it in a **Custom Link**, Salesforce encodes it & turns it into **https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salesforce.com**.

Any ideas?

BTW. here's a screenshot of what I've currently tried.

[image: Custom Link with URL Field]

Answer (score 0):

You can use vf page as `Content Source`:

[image]

vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <script>
    window.open('{!Account.Poc_Url__c}','_self');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

You may need to create it for Case in your case.